# Will IOS HTML5 offline app be listed in appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, html, app-store

I am new to IOS development (currently, I'm developing websites in ASP.NET) and I found out that one can create an IOS app using just html 5 and javascript.

Well that is great news for me since I don't have the time to learn Obj-C and xCode way of writing apps.

I have heard some opposing statements, though, on whether I will be able to submit my app into the app store.

Will I be able to submit such app in the app store?
If not, is there a way to 'wrap it up' somehow, so it could be submitted?

Thanks!

Comment: Google `phonegap`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only native app will be listed in the App store. To submit apps to the appstore you will always need a paid Apple Developers account.

Native in this case meaning real apps that can be installed.
You can build an app in HTML and Javascript in tools like Phonegap and Titanium. These tools will create a native app which loads the local HTML and try to make it feel like a native app.

Comment: You can create apps in standard HTML, CSS, JS and simply wrap them in a native web view, I have a few apps in the app store that are created this way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a wrapper, like AppMobi (where I work).  This lets you write your app in html, javascript and CSS only.

Comment: Didn't know about AppMobi, might have to try it out! I've been doing it the old fashioned way (XCode and Motodev).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your application in a `UIWebView` container. As far as I know, there's no way to package an HTML5 only app for the App Store. I have four apps in there that are HTML5/Javascript apps, wrapped in a `UIWebView`. There are also third-party frameworks available for this.

Comment: I'm not using any of those frameworks, but I know people who use Phone Gap. There are others, like Titanium.